# MX Linux 上で MySQL が起動しない

Tags: linux, mysql, apt

[A Quick Guide to Using the MySQL APT Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#:%7E:text=Adding%20the%20MySQL%20APT%20Repository&text=Go%20to%20the%20download%20page,package%20for%20your%20Linux%20distribution.&text=Note%20that%20the%20same%20package,supported%20Debian%20and%20Ubuntu%20platforms.)を参考にMX LinuxにMySQLをインストールしました。インストール後`systemctl status mysql`を実行しましたが、

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

のようなエラーが返ってきました。`systemctl status mysqld`を実行した場合

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

で同じエラーでした。`service mysqld status`を実行すると

```
mysqld: unrecognized service
```

のような結果でした。
`sudo mysql_secure_installation`を行った場合

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

というエラーが返ってきました。

一度すべてアンインストールし、インストールし直しても結果は同じでした。
どうすればMySQLが使用できるようになるでしょうか。
MySQLのバージョンは
mysql  Ver 8.0.23 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
です。

Comment: 参考までに、[About Us – MX Linux](https://mxlinux.org/about-us/) の "Our Positions" には "Systemd is included by default but not enabled." と記載されています(デフォルトの init system は SysVinit)。

Comment: 実行されているどのコマンドもステータス確認しているだけで、サービスの起動をされていませんが。。起動しても同じですか？sudo service mysqld start実行後にsudo servide mysqld statusを実行する。

Comment: ```sudo service mysqld start```を実行すると```mysqld: unrecognized service ```となってしまいます...

Comment: https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?p=557086#p557086 より、MX LinuxにMySQLは非対応とのことらしいです。お二方とも、ありがとうございました。

Comment: MX Linuxでもインストールできた事例があるようです。http://blog.mor-maid.info/%E6%8A%80%E8%A1%93%E7%B3%BB/mx%20linux%2019%20%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%20mysql%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます…!!